# How to change the Directory from command prompt using Java code

Tags: java

```
public  void VerifyFiles(File dir) throws IOException{
File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
        //Check if directory
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            //Recursively call file list function on the new directory
            VerifyFiles(file);
        } else {
            try {   

                ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                        "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \" C:\\Users\\e843778\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\EncryptedFiles\" && C:\\Program Files\\PGP Corporation\\PGP Desktop");
                builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
                Process p = builder.start();
                Runtime rt =  Runtime.getRuntime();                          
                String query2 = "cmd /c pgpnetshare -v " + "\"" + file + "\"";
                Process proc = rt.exec(query2);
                proc.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Executing for: " + file);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                String s1 ="";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    if(line.contains("All files and folders are encrypted"))
                        s1+=line;    
                }
                System.out.println(s1);
            }
```

I have to run a pgpnetshare command for all the files in a given directory using command prompt. For that, first i need to change my current directory to other directory. But i was not able to change the directory with the below code. I have checked all the previous answered questions in Stackoverflow.com. But none of them helped me.Please verify the code and please let me know if it needs any corrections. Thanks in advance!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(query2,
        null, new File("directory path"));
```

From the documentation:

```
Process exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)
```

Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process with the specified environment and working directory.

You can always create a .bat file and execute that instead.

Answer (score 0):

you should use using file.getAbsolutePath()
like

```
String query2 = "cmd /c pgpnetshare -v " + "\"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
```

Comment: i am not running the command at file location. it is in other directory